# How to Set RadTime Picker Value on My ASpx Page

Tags: c#, telerik, timepicker, datetime-parsing

In my database I have a Datetime field DaysWorkedArrived

On my Aspx Page I have a RadDatePicker and A RadTimePicker. When I add a new record to the database I can build the datetime string to populate that field.

On My ASPX Edit form I need to split that SQL DateTime Field up and show the Date as the RadDatePicker Selected date and the Time as the RadTimePicker Selected Time.

I have no problem getting the date and showing it on my Edit form.

I cannot get the Selected Time to show on the edit form here is my code I am using:

```
string ArrivedTime = Convert.ToDateTime(d.DaysWorkedArrived).ToShortTimeString();
```

This returns a string value of "4:00 AM" I then use this code in an attempt the set the time for my TimePicker Control

```
TimeSpan startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(ArrivedTime);
            tpArrived.SelectedTime = startTime;
```

And this results in an error "String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.

I have read several article on a time Span and tired some code found on line but can not find any that deals with my situation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"4:00 AM"` cannot be parsed into a `TimeSpan` directly, hence your error.

`DateTime` objects already have a  property that expresses the time as a `TimeSpan`:  [**`DateTime.TimeOfDay`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.timeofday?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(d.DaysWorkedArrived);
tpArrived.SelectedTime = startTime.TimeOfDay;
```